# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select' for SELECT * INTO clause

Tags: sql-server

This is my query:

```
IF  EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TBL_1 ]') 
AND type in (N'U'))

DROP TABLE [dbo].[TBL_1]
    
select * INTO TBL_1     
FROM TBL_2;
```

But I am getting an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'

No idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: I just tried the same query in my machine, it worked fine for me. Are you trying this in any specific database or in the master database?

Comment: Wrap a `BEGIN END` around the `Drop` statement. See if that helps.

Comment: I see now (maybe)... There is an extra space here, `OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[TBL_1 ]') `

Comment: @SS_DBA, yes it was a space thing , apology disturbed for such issue, Thanks ALL

Comment: @shrutiM, It did work fine with space in my machine.